# SystemArgumentNullException occured in Salesforce.Force.dll

Tags: api, authentication

[image: This error], I am getting this error when trying to login to Salesforce and calling an API.The tutorial I am following for this task is [this](https://celedonpartners.com/blog/calling-a-custom-salesforce-rest-endpoint-using-c/)
Any idea what is this error for and how to solve it?

Comment: From message it seems like one of the three values in that call is null. Why don't you log those values prior to calling and then troubleshoot why are null?

Comment: @datasert, I have limited knowledge of .NET/C#, I printed these three values in console but yes nothing was printing.The detail in Force.com toolkit says that when UsernamePasswordAsync completes successfully it gives Access Token and Instance URL. The Instance URL returned identifies the web service URL you'll use to call the Force.com REST APIs, passing in the Access Token. Additionally, the authentication client will return the API version number, which is used to construct a valid HTTP request. Does it means that userid password is not authenticating corectly?